# Why is casting from base to derived giving this functionality?

Tags: c++, casting, radix, derived

I am confused as to why casting a derived class to a pointer of base class calls upon the derived class method when I haven't used the virtual keyword. Is this normal behavior? Doesn't the pointer hold a Person object in memory, therefore casting it to a Student should not have any affect to its contents?

```
  class Person {

    public:

    Person()
    {
        cout << "Creating Person Class" << endl;
    }

    void about_me()
    {
        cout << "I am a person" << endl;
    }
};

class Student : protected Person {
    public:
    Student()
    {
        cout << "Creating Student Class" << endl;
    }

    void about_me()
    {
        cout << " I am a student " << endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    Person* pperson = new Person();
    Student* pstudent = new Student();

    pperson->about_me();
    pstudent->about_me();

    pperson-> about_me();

    ((Student*)pperson)-> about_me(); // this is the line where I do the cast

    return 0;

}
```

The output of the code is the following

```
  Creating Person Class
Creating Person Class
Creating Student Class
I am a person
 I am a student 
I am a person
 I am a student
```

Comment: You're encountering Undefined Behaviour. Avoid C-style casts in C++, use `dynamic_cast<T>` instead and you'll get a runtime exception. What's happening in your case is the C-style cast causes the compiler to make a static (non-virtual) call to `Student::about_me`.

Comment: Well, you are telling your compiler to treat the pointer as `Student`, so it will. Why are you surprised?

Comment: No, it doesn't call the derived class's method. Your output clearly shows that the fourth call is to the base class's method. You're mistaken.

Comment: @Dai "*use `dynamic_cast<T>` instead and you'll get a runtime exception*" - only when using it with references, not pointers. `dynamic_cast` returns null on failure when casting a pointer. Accessing a null pointer is not guaranteed to generate a runtime exception, especially when the called method doesn't access `this` for anything.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the cast had any effect on the contents? Have the contents changed?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Methinks the OP subscribes to the beginner misconception that methods belong to object instances (like how JavaScript function properties work) instead of being static behind-the-scenes, so if that's true (which it isn't) then it follows that `pperson`'s object value must be mutated internally somehow in order for `pperson->about_me` to print `Student::about_me`. (I used to think this too when I was new, I thought adding too many methods to a class would somehow slow it down).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your code "works" because neither of your `about_me()` methods access their respective `this` pointers for anything.

Technically speaking, what you are doing is **undefined behavior**, because `pperson` does not point at a valid `Student` object, but you are telling the compiler to treat it as if it were.  So literally *anything* can happen.

In *many* common compiler implementations, a class method call like `pperson->about_me()` is actually calling more like `about_me(pperson)`, where `about_me()` gets implemented as a standalone function with a `this` input parameter.  So code you have shown *might* be implementation by the compiler more like this under the hood (not exactly, but you should get the idea):

```
struct Person
{
};

void Person_Person(Person *this)
{
    cout << "Creating Person Class" << endl;
}

void Person_about_me(Person *this)
{
    cout << "I am a person" << endl;
}

struct Student
{
};

void Student_Student(Student *this)
{
    Person_Person(this);
    cout << "Creating Student Class" << endl;
}

void Student_about_me(Student *this)
{
    cout << " I am a student " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    //Person* pperson = new Person();
    byte *buf1 = new byte[sizeof(Person)];
    Person* pperson = (Person*) buf1;
    Person_Person(pperson);

    //Student* pstudent = new Student();
    byte *buf2 = new byte[sizeof(Student)];
    Student* pstudent = (Student*) buf2;
    Student_Student(pstudent);

    //pperson->about_me();
    Person_about_me(pperson);

    //pstudent->about_me();
    Student_about_me(pstudent);

    //pperson-> about_me();
    Person_about_me(pperson);

    //((Student*)pperson)-> about_me();
    Student_about_me((Student*)pperson);

    return 0;
}
```

So, in the 4th call to `about_me()`, you are instructing the compiler to call `Student::about_me()` instead of letting it call `Person::about_me()` normally, with its `this` parameter set to a `Person*` pointer that is type-casted to `Student*`.  Since `this` is not dereferenced by `about_me()`, the call is "successful" in that you see the "expected" output.  It doesn't matter what `this` points to in this case, because it is not being used.

Now, try adding some data members to your classes, and then output those members in `about_me()`, and you will see very different, very unexpected/random results, due to the undefined behavior you are invoking.  For example:

```
class Person
{
protected:
    string m_name;

public:

    Person(const string &name)
        : m_name(name)
    {
        cout << "Creating Person Class" << endl;
    }

    void about_me()
    {
        cout << "I am a person, my name is " << m_name << endl;
    }
};

class Student : protected Person
{
private:
    int m_id;
    string m_school;

public:

    Student(const string &name, int id, const string &school)
        : Person(name), m_id(id), m_school(school)
    {
        cout << "Creating Student Class" << endl;
    }

    void about_me()
    {
        cout << "I am a student, my name is " << m_name << ", my id is " << m_id << " at " << m_school << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person* pperson = new Person("John Doe");
    Student* pstudent = new Student("Jane Doe", 12345, "Some School");

    pperson->about_me(); // "I am a person, my name is John Doe"
    pstudent->about_me(); // "I am a student, my name is Jane Doe, my id is 12345 at Some School"

    pperson->about_me(); // "I am a person, my name is John Doe"

    ((Student*)pperson)->about_me(); // runtime error!

    delete pstudent;
    delete pperson;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/eYLhSD)